# How to easily extract request.POST data after Django form submission?

Tags: html, django, post, django-forms

My request.POST data looks like this after my Django form submission:

<QueryDict: {'form-0-country': ['19389'], 'form-0-city': ['Montreal'], 'form-0-eid': ['450'], 'form-0-company': ['Nestle'], 'form-0-dept': ['HR'], 'form-1-country': ['19390'], 'form-1-city': ['Toronto'], 'form-1-eid': ['432'], 'form-1-company': ['Nestle'], 'form-1-dept': ['Finance']}>

These are values of two forms contained in two different rows on the webpage. The values from these two rows are printed sequentially in the request.POST. Is there a way to get this data printed in the backend in a simpler way so that I don't have to loop through all this data to extract the specific fields contained in it?

For eg. something like this:
`<QueryDict: {'form-0-country': ['19389','19390'], 'form-0-city': ['Montreal','Toronto'], 'form-0-eid': ['450'], 'form-0-company': ['Nestle','Nestle'], 'form-0-dept': ['HR','Finance']>`
so that I can easily loop through the value (lists) in the dict above.

instead of:
`<QueryDict: {'form-0-country': ['19389'], 'form-0-city': ['Montreal'], 'form-0-eid': ['450'], 'form-0-company': ['Nestle'], 'form-0-dept': ['HR'], 'form-1-country': ['19390'], 'form-1-city': ['Toronto'], 'form-1-eid': ['432'], 'form-1-company': ['Nestle'], 'form-1-dept': ['Finance']}>`

Here is my code snippet:

````
if request.method == 'POST':
  form = CreationForm(request.POST)
  
  if form.is_valid():                         
             form.save()
             print(form.cleaned_data)```
````

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cleaned_data` to extract the values from your form.

For example:

```
country = form.cleaned_data["country"]
city = form.cleaned_data["city"]
```

Comment: thanks, I've tried that but when I try cleaned_data I get "None" even though I can see the submitted data when I print request.POST. Any ideas why?

Comment: Any thoughts please?

Comment: Hi @xis10z, you may need to add `form = MyForm(request.POST)` to your code before calling `cleaned_data `. Also, can you please try `country = request.POST.get('country')` and let me know what is the output displayed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried that here is the result:
country = request.POST.get('form-0-country')
output>> 19389 (this is the site id from the models db I guess)

Comment: also, I was already using this form = MyForm(request.POST).

Comment: You may use `request.POST.get()` instead of `cleaned_data` as it is returning the expecting value.

Comment: Actually I have multiple forms on the page and new forms can be added so there is no fixed number of forms and it was getting a bit complicated to run loop through all that POST data when multiple forms are submitted in POST. That's why I wanted to use cleaned_data to get the data nicely organized.

Answer (score 0):

You should print form instead of printing `request.POST`

e.g.

```py
def your_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = YourForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
             print(form.cleaned_data)
             ...
             ...
             ...
```

Comment: Yes, I tried that and it's None for me even then:
{'Country': None, 'City': None, 'eid': None, 'company': None, 'dept': 'HR'}
Only value I see is for 'dept' which is an independent input field on the form and not a part of the models.py where I have defined the other fields that get used in my forms class.

Comment: Any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: @xis10z Can you add your template and your forms.py ?